# Icons not showing

Tags: themes

I'm having a problem with icons not showing in my WordPress site. As you can see in the attached image some of the icons in the admin bar aren't showing. The same is also happening in parts of the theme. See here: http://www.thisisutil.com/product/bowl/ (Look under "Share this product").

Do you know why is this happening?

[image: Admin bar missing icons]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Benoti for pointing me in the right direction. What happened was that I was overriding all font styles with `*{...}` in the theme style.css.

Answer (score 2):

It's look like fontawesome fonts are not available.

In the `fontawesome.css` the path is `../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot`

Verify this path, correct it if fonts are another folder.

The css is waiting for this structure

```
---theme
     fonts
       fontawesome-webfont.eot
       ...
     css
       fontawesome.css
       ...
```

But your structure is maybe

```
--- theme
      fontawesome.css

      fonts
         fontawesome-webfont.eot
         ...
```